# Go reference in for loop sets the wrong reference

Tags: go

I'm trying to set a reference in a for loop in Go.

I have the following code (https://play.golang.org/p/knsVC2gMSCL):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct{ Name string }

func main() {
  persons := []Person{
    Person{
      Name: "Sebastiaan",
    },
    Person{
      Name: "Melle",
    },
  }

  var sebastiaan *Person
  for _, person := range persons {
    if person.Name == "Sebastiaan" {
      sebastiaan = &person
    }
  }

  fmt.Printf("sebastiaan: %+v\n", sebastiaan)
}
```

I would expect the `sebastiaan` variable to have the value the Sebastiaan person, but when I run this code I get the following:

```
sebastiaan: &{Name:Melle}
```

Does anyone know how this is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting a reference to the *loop counter*.
This means that the `&person` reference will always be the last item in the array.

You can solve this in 2 ways.

**Make a copy of the loop counter**

You can make a copy of the loop counter, and set a reference to it like this:

```golang
if person.Name == "Sebastiaan" {
    copy := person
    sebastiaan = &copy
}
```

**Don't use references**

You can also fix it by not using a reference to the loop counter.
You can achieve this by changing the `persons` array to pointers like so:

```golang
persons := []*Person{
    &Person{
        Name: "Sebastiaan",
    },
    &Person{
        Name: "Melle",
    },
}
```

And then this code works as expected.

```golang
if person.Name == "Sebastiaan" {
    sebastiaan = person
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, making a copy fixed the problem!

Answer (score 2):

In Go the loop variable is reused. The last value put in `person` variable is Melle so it is still there after the loop finishes. The `sebastiaan` variable is a pointer so it takes no copy of the `person` value.

You can fix it by changing type of `sebastiaan` to `Person` from `*Person`.